# Why an iframe does not load when embedded into a Web App page?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications

I tried to load this html code onto a Google script:

`<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>`

saved the file with the name "page" then used this in the Google script:

`function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page');
}`

It views the iframe, but with no content. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot show iframes inside Apps Script.

Comment: I don't think there was anything wrong with the HTML code, so I'm guessing you're right. But what if I add an iframe gadget to a google sites and let a script handle it using the sites API (`getHtmlContent` and `setHtmlContent`), is it valid?

Comment: That would work. The key is that you can't show an iframe inside the script's own content.